# Grouping Telerik WPF RadGrid Cells

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid from Telerik RadControls for WPF. i have this requirement where by the header column should remain as it is, but the grid entries are required to merge cells as required. i am attaching an image, showing a sample of what i require. Can this be done in RadGrid? If so, how?[image]